# [FFmpeg]what is replacements of avpicture_alloc,avpicture::data which were deprecated

Tags: ffmpeg

I am modifying example source code(muxing.c) from FFmpeg site.
I changed old functions to new ones and tried to build the code.
then, there are several errrors said AVPicture was declared deprecated.

I did some research on the internet but couldn't find the answer how to fix it.

```
/* Allocate the encoded raw picture. */
ret = avpicture_alloc(&dst_picture, c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height);
if (ret < 0)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate picture: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
    char buf[256];
    av_strerror(ret, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("Could not allocate picture: %s,ret:%d\n", buf, ret);
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is [`av_image_alloc()`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/group__lavu__picture.html#ga841e0a89a642e24141af1918a2c10448)

I also couldn't find what the replacement is and I found in the source of [AVPicture](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/avpicture_8c_source.html) that `avpicture_alloc` simply calls that function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, kfazi !

Comment: and if you don't mind, come to check my another question. I'm tying to convert jpg files to a movie file(Mjpeg type). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586467/ffmpeghow-to-make-codes-for-converting-jpg-files-to-avimotion-jpeg

Comment: It's unbelievable. What kind of developer is altering the code without documentating it...

Answer (score -1):

I just change my compiler's behaviour

with this

+#pragma warning(disable:4996)

It could be only a temporary solution